# PhpStorm. Ignore deprecated groupId: editor for id: editor.preferences.import

Tags: phpstorm

My PhpStorm generating many errors like this:

```
[3188093]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - ignore deprecated groupId: editor for id: editor.preferences.import
```

How can I solve it? I tried totally removed existing settings, so it means that I didn't import anything from previous version. I'm using latest **PhpStorm 2016.1.2**

Comment: This is most likely from a plugin in your IDE that is still using deprecated code, and not really something to stress about until the deprecated code is removed from your IDE, however by then you will have updated your IDE and the plugins that come with it

Comment: Thanks @KevinCrain